# Need tags like <sounds> <vocal> etc?

Tags: discussion, tags

Questions like [How did the roar evolve from snort?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/15947/how-did-the-roar-evolve-from-snort)

and others https://biology.stackexchange.com/search?q=roar

could maybe use tags like [sounds](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sounds), [vocals](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocals) etc.?

Answer (score 3):

There is [communication](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/communication) and [ethology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethology), which are both relevant for all questions dealing with different forms of animal communication. Maybe we also need a more specific [animal-communication](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-communication) (or [zoosemiotics](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zoosemiotics)). For a tag dealing with auditory animal communication I would prefer [animal-vocalization](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/animal-vocalization) (or just [vocalization](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocalization)). Some sort of vocalization tag would probably be usefuls to also deal with physiological issues/adaptations for animal vocalization. I don't like [sounds](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sounds), since it's very vague and could be used for widely different purposes.